# Disable index mapping creation for Hibernate Search using Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, hibernate-search

I'm using Hibernate Search for Elasticsearch (5.8.2.Final) and Elasticsearch (6.0). I'm new Hibernate Search and I'm aware that Hibernate Search for Elasticsearch is experimental. I'm also aware that Hibernate 6 is going to bring some improvements for use with ES. However, in the meantime, i'm finding that the annotations are not allowing me to create the types of index mappings i want and I was wondering if there was a way to disable the creation of the index mapping entirely. I'd like to allow ES to apply an index template to my index when Hibernate first creates it. I've read the docs and stepped through the code but I am not seeing anything that would allow me to do this. Is this possible?

Thank you.

Comment: I've found a way around my problem. I am able to create an index template and have it applied on top of the mapping that is created by Hibernate Search. This however doesn't answer my original question about having the ability to disable the index mapping creation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable index *and* mapping creation altogether (see Sanne's answer), but you cannot currently ask Hibernate Search to create indexes without creating mappings.

One solution would be for you to create your indexes beforehand. After all, if you're fine with adding templates, why not add the indexes too?

Another solution: you could try the `update` strategy. If your custom mapping is compatible with the one generated by Hibernate Search, they might simply get merged. Be careful **not to use this in production** though, since a failure with the `update` strategy will leave you in deep trouble (see [the warnings in the documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.8/reference/en-US/html_single/#elasticsearch-schema-management-strategy)).

Comment: i came back to mention this in regards to disabling management that its also doesnt create the index. i'd prefer if it would create the index then all i would need to do is deal with the templates myself but this will have to do for now. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To skip creating the index definitions:

```
hibernate.search.default.elasticsearch.index_schema_management_strategy none
```

See also [11.3.4. Hibernate Search configuration](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.9/reference/en-US/html_single/#elasticsearch-integration-configuration)

Comment: for whatever reason when i originally read that setting, i took it as something completely different. I'll give it a try and report back.

Comment: this also disables the index creation which i guess isnt the end of the world but it would be nice if there were better options around controlling the mapping outright which i'm sure is coming in future releases. Thank you for your response.